# apache velocity to ignore \n in token?

Tags: velocity, apache-velocity

Is there a way to tell apache velocity to ignore \n in tokens?
For the following password token (line number 2)
The output is on line number 6 and 7

**update** 
someone marked this as Duplicate, its not, in my case the new line are in the token

[image]

Comment: It's not a duplicate: here newlines are *inside* references, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked the following example:

```
#set($value="123\n123")
<label>$value<\label>
```

The printout is: "123\n123"

As long as you print out your variable in quotes it should print it as is and not convert the "\n" to a new line.